# Is there a way to display a part of an image depending on the size using CSS only?

Tags: css, typescript

I would like to inquire if is it possible to display only the part of an image depending on the image width x height using only CSS?  (If it is not possible with only CSS then TypeScript only)

Example if I have an image which is 2,434px × 1,697px inside a div that is around 700x700, how to show only a particular part, like the whole upper part of the image only?

```css
.image-container {
  height: 700px;
  width: 700px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Sunflower_from_Silesia2.jpg">
</div>
```

From the code it shows only somewhat the upper left, but I need the whole upper part of the image: like below
[needed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uTkH.png)

Answer (score 1):

`object-fit` and `object-position` can help you here:

```css
.image-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 700px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Sunflower_from_Silesia2.jpg">
</div>
```